# Null output from field calculator code block

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, field-calculator, python-parser

I have a simple calculation to compare two columns and populate a new column with the lower value but I am getting null output...any ideas?

expression

```
re_score(!Signal_Strength!,!Signal_Strength_1!,out1)
```

code block

```
out1='99'
def re_score(f1,f2,out1):
 if f1<f2:
  out1 = f1
 else:
  out1=f2
 return out1
```

> WARNING 000405: No records within table Succeeded at Tue Mar 06
>   15:13:45 2012 (Elapsed Time: 7.00 seconds)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can evaluate your expression using a simple inline-if statement (does not require codeblock):

```
!Signal_Strength! if !Signal_Strength! < !Signal_Strength_1! else !Signal_Strength_1!
```

---

Or rework your codeblock:

```
def re_score(f1,f2):
    if f1 < f2:
        out1 = f1
    else:
        out1 = f2
    return out1
```

with expression:

```
re_score(!Signal_Strength!, !Signal_Strength_1!)
```

Comment: thanks...it was a dataset issue where the model was not updating itself properly. I added out1 in "strange"/extra places for error trapping - I could search for 99.